# multiple toplevel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, toplevel

I have a form "liste of customer" in the right there is a button when u click on it it's show another form named "search" it's let u search by a diff fields this form has a propriety **TopLevel=true** when user want to search for ex by bank account it's show another form which content the list of accounts this form also has to be on the top I mean has also propriety **TopLevel=true** but when I execute the code it doesn't work.

Please help me.

NB: TopLevel it s the same propriety as topmost.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ShowDialog()` method instead of `Show()` e.g.

```
Search.ShowDialog()
Accounts.ShowDialog()
```